# Scala Pass window partition dataset to UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe like below,

| Id1 | Id2 | Id3 | TaskId | TaskName | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | dfr3ws-45d | randomName1 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | er98d3-lkj | randomName2 | 2 |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | hu77d9-mnb | randomName3 | 3 |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | xc33d5-rew | deployhere4 | 4 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | dfr3ws-45d | randomName1 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | er98d3-lkj | deployhere2 | 2 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | hu77d9-mnb | randomName3 | 3 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | xc33d5-rew | randomName4 | 4 |

I partitioned the data using Id3 and Id2 and added the row_number.

I need to perform the below condition:

TaskId "hu77d9-mnb" should come before the task name which contains deploy in it. As the table suggests above the name will be random I need to read each name in the partition and see which name contains deploy in it.

if deploy taskName index is greater than taskID index then I mark the value as 1 otherwise 0.

I need to get final table like this:

| Id1 | Id2 | Id3 | TaskId | TaskName | index | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | dfr3ws-45d | randomName1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | er98d3-lkj | randomName2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | hu77d9-mnb | randomName3 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | bc123-234 | xc33d5-rew | deployhere4 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | dfr3ws-45d | randomName1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | er98d3-lkj | deployhere2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | hu77d9-mnb | randomName3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | 11 | xre43-876 | xc33d5-rew | randomName4 | 4 | 0 |

I am stuck at this place how can I pass the partition data to UDF (or other functions like UDAF) and perform this task. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index of "deploy" row and index of specific row ("hu77d9-mnb") can be assigned to each row with Window "first" function, and then just compared:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 11, "bc123-234", "dfr3ws-45d", "randomName1", 1),
  (1, 11, "bc123-234", "er98d3-lkj", "randomName2", 2),
  (1, 11, "bc123-234", "hu77d9-mnb", "randomName3", 3),
  (1, 11, "bc123-234", "xc33d5-rew", "deployhere4", 4),
  (1, 11, "xre43-876", "dfr3ws-45d", "randomName1", 1),
  (1, 11, "xre43-876", "er98d3-lkj", "deployhere2", 2),
  (1, 11, "xre43-876", "hu77d9-mnb", "randomName3", 3),
  (1, 11, "xre43-876", "xc33d5-rew", "randomName4", 4)
).toDF("Id1", "Id2", "Id3", "TaskID", "TaskName", "index")

val specificTaskId = "hu77d9-mnb"
val idsWindow = Window.partitionBy("Id1", "Id2", "Id3")

df.withColumn("deployIndex",
  first(
    when(instr($"TaskName", "deploy") > 0, $"index").otherwise(null),
    true)
    .over(idsWindow))

  .withColumn("specificTaskIdIndex",
    first(
      when($"TaskID" === lit(specificTaskId), $"index").otherwise(null),
      true)
      .over(idsWindow))

  .withColumn("result",
    when($"specificTaskIdIndex" > $"deployIndex", 0).otherwise(1)
  )
```

Output ("deployIndex" and "specificTaskIdIndex" columns have to be dropped):

```
+---+---+---------+----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-------------------+------+
|Id1|Id2|Id3      |TaskID    |TaskName   |index|deployIndex|specificTaskIdIndex|result|
+---+---+---------+----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-------------------+------+
|1  |11 |bc123-234|dfr3ws-45d|randomName1|1    |4          |3                  |1     |
|1  |11 |bc123-234|er98d3-lkj|randomName2|2    |4          |3                  |1     |
|1  |11 |bc123-234|hu77d9-mnb|randomName3|3    |4          |3                  |1     |
|1  |11 |bc123-234|xc33d5-rew|deployhere4|4    |4          |3                  |1     |
|1  |11 |xre43-876|dfr3ws-45d|randomName1|1    |2          |3                  |0     |
|1  |11 |xre43-876|er98d3-lkj|deployhere2|2    |2          |3                  |0     |
|1  |11 |xre43-876|hu77d9-mnb|randomName3|3    |2          |3                  |0     |
|1  |11 |xre43-876|xc33d5-rew|randomName4|4    |2          |3                  |0     |
+---+---+---------+----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-------------------+------+
```

Comment: Hi @pasha701, Thank you for your answer, it helped me with my problem. I marked it as correct. Cheers!

Comment: When I change the null inside otherwise to 0, I am getting all the values as 0 the condition is not working. Any idea why that is happenning.

Comment: Not clear why to change it. Null is used by "first" function for get first non-null value.

Comment: When I have Null for $"specificTaskIdIndex" or $"deployIndex" the condition greater than always returns 1. 1) For example, null > 35 gives 1 as result. 2) second example 23 > null also give 1. 3) null > null also 1.

Comment: Guess, better leave "specificTaskIdIndex" and "deployIndex" evaluation without modification, and take nulls into account during "result" evaluation.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same idea. Cheers